# Hide div permanently once closed regardless of page reload

Tags: javascript, html

I am after some help if at all possible.

I would like it so that once someone has clicked the X it wont re show the parent div when the page is reloaded or the user navigates to another page with the same popup.

I have the code below for where I started and hope I am only a little off!

Thanks in advance for any help :)

```js
  $(".banner-cta-close").click(function() {
    $("body").addClass("header-banner-hide");
  }); 



  $(document).ready(function() {
    if (sessionStorage["PopupShown"] != 'yes') {
      ShowDialog(true);
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });

$("#btnClose").click(function(e) {
  HideDialog();
  e.preventDefault();
  sessionStorage["PopupShown"] = 'yes'; //Save in the sessionStorage if the modal has been shown
});

function ShowDialog(modal) {
  $('#div_with_text').hide(); // this or use css to hide the div
  $('#div_with_text').delay(5000).slideDown('slow');

  if (modal) {
    $("#div_with_text").unbind("click");
  } else {
    $("#div_with_text").click(function(e) {
      HideDialog();
    });
  }
}

function HideDialog() {
  $("#div_with_text").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_with_text">
  <div class="container">text
    <div class="bannerbuttonhover" style="background: #2f358f;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border-radius: 2px;
cursor: pointer;">Sign Up now</div>

    <div class="banner-cta-close">X</div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You can use session storage (cookies for example) for that

Comment: try localStorage instead if session storage doesn't work.. `localStorage.setItem(name)`, `localStorage.getItem(name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an App Server, you could send a message back to the server to tell the server not send the code for the dialog on reload. But if not, you could use localStorage (shown here)

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if (!window.localStorage || !window.localStorage.getItem('NoPopup')) {
      ShowDialog(true);
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });

$("#btnClose").click(function(e) {
  HideDialog();
  e.preventDefault();
  if (window.localStorage) window.localStorage.setItem("NoPopup","true");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As @ControlAltDel mentioned , you can avoid sending its code from the server.
Otherwise, If you want to do it in the front-end you can simply use cookies ... You can find how to do it with javascript in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie).
Depending on the cookie value, you can either show this div or not.